# Libvirt command line arguments using xml config file

Tags: xml, libvirt, qemu, kvm-virtualization

I am trying something similar to http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/QEMUSwitchToLibvirt#-s . This is my xml file :

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>rubis_ws</name>
  <uuid>1a474ca9-604f-aceb-2fed-792fe1e9f900</uuid>
  <memory>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel5.4.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2' cache='none'/>
      <source file='/root/incremental.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'/>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:16:3e:98:78:04'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
        <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' keymap='en-us'/>
        <video>
          <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
        </video>
      </devices>

      <qemu:commandline>
        <qemu:arg value='-s'/>
      </qemu:commandline>
    </domain>
```

I start the VM from this xml file. Now When I do "ps aux | grep rubis" , I get :

root     13496 59.1  3.5 1266168 292112 ?      Sl   16:50   0:23 /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -S -M rhel5.4.0 -m 1024 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -name rubis_ws -uuid 1a474ca9-604f-aceb-2fed-792fe1e9f900 -monitor unix:/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/rubis_ws.monitor,server,nowait -no-kvm-pit-reinjection -boot c -drive file=/root/incremental.img,if=ide,bus=0,unit=0,boot=on,format=qcow2,cache=none -net nic,macaddr=00:16:3e:98:78:04,vlan=0 -net tap,fd=18,vlan=0 -serial pty -parallel none -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -k en-us -vga cirrus -balloon virtio

root     13531  0.0  0.0  61192   760 pts/5    S+   16:51   0:00 grep rubis

I cannot find the -s in that command . Can you please let me know whether I am making any mistake. I have been stuck with this for a long time without knowing how to solve it. 
My ultimate aim is to make this command argument work and use it for -incoming tag using qemu command line argument with libvirt.

Thanks for your help.

- Regards,
  Sethu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on what distro are you doing this? Might be that your libvirt build is too old to support this option

Comment: I see. Im using libvirt 0.8.2 .Its not supported in this distro ?